# Composite Key for Shopping Cart, SQL, Logic Model

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am making a logic model for a shopping cart project and I got to the next question.
What would happen if I want to add 2 equal products (examples: 2 pencils)?

logical model: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojzgi.png)
physical model:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHmCd.png)

A solution I thought is to make a compound key or compound attribute that stores in the first part an incremental int attribute and in the second part the product id, so you could enter the cart 2 products that despite having the same product_id in the second part are different in the first part which is incremental.

What do you think? Is it a good idea or does someone have a better solution?

```
CREATE TABLE Carro 
(
 id_carro INTEGER NOT NULL 
)
ALTER TABLE Carro ADD CONSTRAINT Carro_PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id_carro)
 WITH (
 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON , 
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON )

CREATE TABLE Orden_Detalle 
(
 id_ord_det INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL , 
 Carro_id_carro INTEGER NOT NULL , 
 Producto_id_prod INTEGER NOT NULL 
)

ALTER TABLE Orden_Detalle ADD CONSTRAINT Orden_Detalle_PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id_ord_det, Producto_id_prod)
 WITH (
 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON , 
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON )

CREATE TABLE Producto 
(
 id_prod INTEGER NOT NULL , 
 name_prod VARCHAR (20) , 
 value_prod INTEGER 
)
ALTER TABLE Producto ADD CONSTRAINT Producto_PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id_prod)
 WITH (
 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON , 
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON )

ALTER TABLE Orden_Detalle 
ADD CONSTRAINT Orden_Detalle_Carro_FK FOREIGN KEY 
( 
 Carro_id_carro
) 
REFERENCES Carro 
( 
 id_carro 
) 

ALTER TABLE Orden_Detalle 
ADD CONSTRAINT Orden_Detalle_Producto_FK FOREIGN KEY 
( 
 Producto_id_prod
) 
REFERENCES Producto 
( 
 id_prod 
)
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is a english language site. Please translate the question to english and post it

Comment: English edition ready

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have two tables for Orders: OrderMaster, OrderDetails. This way, you can see all the details for a specific Order. I am  assuming that every order has got one-one mapping with cart.

For your question, you don't need composite key. Just incremental Order details Id is enough. You can find order details for an order using OrderId.

- **OrderMaster :** OrderId(Incremental, PK),CartId(FK)
- **OrderDetails:** OrderDetailsId(Incremental, PK),OrderId(FK),ProductId(FK)
- **Cart:**   CartId(PK), CartName, ...
- **Product:** ProductId(PK), ProductName, ProductValue ...